# Why wont my code work

Tags: javascript, html

I have just started on a new short game and i am trying to figure out how to make a reward when i reach a certain value I expect that the counter starts at zero, and each time the button is clicked it goes up by one, until it reaches 10, then the next time the button is pressed the counter should go up by 2. Instead, I find that clicking the button does not change the displayed count.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <body>
    
<p>
    The button was clicked
    <span class="total-clicks"></span>
    times
</p>

<button id="btn1" onclick="addClick()">
    Click Me!
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let clicks = 0;
    let click_power = 1;
    let reward_recevied = false;

    function addClick() {
    clicks = clicks + click_power;
    if(clicks >= 10 && reward_received == false) {
        click_power = click_power + 1;
        reward_received = true;
    }
}
    function addClick() {
        clicks = clicks + 1;
        document.querySelector('.total-clicks').textContent
            = clicks;
    }



    

    // Simulate click function
    function clickButton() {
        document.querySelector('#btn1').click();
    }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No need to apologize, just be specific. Something like "I expect that the counter starts at zero, and each time the button is clicked it goes up by one, until it reaches 10, then the next time the button is pressed the counter should go up by 2. Instead, I find that clicking the button does not change the displayed count. The browser's javascript console displays the following errors..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to increase the first 10 times the variable clicks + 1, and after 10, clicks + 2 you need to make sure that the names of the variables in the code are `reward_received` everywhere and write the code for the `addClick()` function once.

In your code you overwrite `addClick()` function by writing it a second time.

You can view errors in your javascript if you open the HTML file in the browser by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Here is probably the code you wanted:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            The button was clicked
            <span class="total-clicks"></span>
            times
        </p>
        <button id="btn1" onclick="addClick()">
            Click Me!
        </button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            let clicks = 0;
            let click_power = 1;
            let reward_received = false;

            function addClick() {
            clicks = clicks + click_power;
                if(clicks >= 10 && reward_received == false) {
                    click_power = click_power + 1;
                    reward_received = true;
                }
                document.querySelector('.total-clicks').textContent = clicks;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```